# minimum API level list in Unity 2019.2.5f1 is missing

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-sdk-tools

I am creating a VR App for android 8 on unity. I have installed android SDK that comes with unity. Later, I have also installed Android SDK (build 27 and 28 and 29.02) through Android Studio. When I go for selecting the minimum API level, the list does not open.

I have tried the SDKs from the sources too. I am a nooby.

Error 1:
If I build the app. This error comes :

```
UnityException: Minimum API Level Not Supported on Requested VR Device 
Cardboard Requires a Minimum API Level of 19. You have selected 16 UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)`
```

Error 2:

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)`
```

Error 3:

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00242] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:190 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:95 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Comment: probably related https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-cant-set-minimum-api-level.638323 - though also no solution yet .. but you're not alone apparently

Comment: and also https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-android-ndk-missing.689122 ... apparently NDK r19 comes with Unity 2019.3